# CSP error trying to post in Flask-Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, flask, axios, content-security-policy

Im trying to do a simple post request from a vue client using axios to my flask backend. After getting some CORS errors, i've installed flask-cors, searched the right configuration for CORS(), set the headers for the axios post method but im getting a Cannot POST /login reply when i try the request. Console shows:

> *Error: Request aborted* 
>   *Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).*
>   *Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“default-src”).*
>   *Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at http://localhost:8080/favicon.ico (“default-src”).*
>   *Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at eval (“default-src”).*

The concerning code whould be

```
#__init__.py
from flaskps.config import Config
from flask_cors import CORS
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config) # my configs

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('flask_cors').level = logging.DEBUG

CORS(app,resources={r'/.*':{'origins':'http://localhost:8080/'}},supports_credentials=True) 
app.add_url_rule( "/autenticacion",    'auth_authenticate',    auth.authenticate,    methods=['POST'])
```

I prefer not using route decorator. It was a big app done with Jinja2 templates and im now trying to pass it to Vue. I've changed the authenthicate method to just return a json

```
#auth.py
def authenticate():
    print(request.form)
    return jsonify("Exito usuario registrado")
```

Used a small router that works fine, this is one of the views

```
//login.vue which used a Login component that i took out to clear any troubling code
<template>
    <div class="login_view">
    <form class="form-signin" @submit="onSubmit" method="POST">
            <label class="sr-only">Correo</label>
            <input v-model="email" type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo" required autofocus>
            <label class="sr-only">Clave</label>
            <input v-model="password" type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Clave" required>
            <br>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-light btn-block" type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

import axios from 'axios'
export default {
    name: 'login_view',
    data :function() {
        return{
            email:'',
            password:''
        }
    },
    methods :{
        initForm() {
            this.email = ''
            this.password = ''
        },
        doLogin(payload){
            const headers = {            
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }
            axios.post("http://localhost:5000/autenticacion", payload, {
                headers: headers
            })
                .then(response => console.log(response))
        },
        onSubmit(){
            console.log("Submited")
            const payload = {
                email: this.email,
                password: this.password
            }
            this.doLogin(payload)
        }     
    },
}
</script>
```

I've tried with different headers in the axios post, and simpler params for CORS method but no variant has worked 
example.log shows the following:

DEBUG:flask_cors.extension:Configuring CORS with resources: {'/*': {'origins': ['http://localhost:8080/'], 'methods': 'DELETE, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT', 'allow_headers': ['.*'], 'expose_headers': None, 'supports_credentials': True, 'max_age': None, 'send_wildcard': False, 'automatic_options': True, 'vary_header': True, 'resources': {'/*': {'origins': 'http://localhost:8080/'}}, 'intercept_exceptions': True, 'always_send': True}}
WARNING:werkzeug: * Debugger is active!
INFO:werkzeug: * Debugger PIN: 160-985-678

If you need any other example code just tell
thanks!

Comment: The errors cited in the question are Content-Security-Policy errors, not CORS errors.

Comment: Corrected question. I still do not know what these errors mean